# How can I create a custom user profile page without overlapping the registration and login pages?

Tags: views, 8

I'd like to create a custom user profile page, but if I use `/user/%` path then it will also overlap `/user/registration`, `/user/login` and so on...

Is there any ways to avoid it?

Comment: welcome to the community!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

- customize the user profile page at `/admin/config/people/accounts/display`
- Change anything if you implement the [hook_preprocess_user()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK).
- Add blocks at `admin/structure/block`.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to create a custom template file for the user.

add a bit of code to your .theme file:

**MYTHEME.theme:**

```
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_user(&$suggestions, $variables, $hook) {

  // Define the view mode.
  $mode = $variables['elements']['#view_mode'];
  // Create a theme hook suggestion which has the view mode name in it.
  $suggestions[] = 'user__' . $mode;

}
```

The above tells Drupal to look for template files that fit the new naming conventions.

Then create a twig template file in `MYTHEME/templates`:

**user--full.html.twig**

```
<div class="user-full-wrapper">

    {% if content.user_picture | render %}
          {{ content.user_picture }}
    {% endif %}

    {% if content.field_name | render %}
          <p>{{ content.field_name }}</p>
    {% endif %}

</div>
```

The above html is just an example.

Now you have unique markup for just the user profile page in Drupal. From there it's just a matter of choosing fields, and adding styling.

Make sure to clear cache so Drupal will register your new twig file!